# How to add a number into array name

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, while-loop

I have 5 arrays with 8 strings inside each. Each array has a name fallowed by number like 'titles1', 'titles2'... I want to create a while loop to check each string in each array. The problem that I currently have is that I am not able to change number in array names (from 1 to 5 - titles1, 2, 3 ...). Any idea how I could make it work? The code works however because the array name is a string now, it is not checking anything inside arrays.

```
var i = 0; var j = 1; var titles = '';
while(j <= 5) {
    titles = 'titles' + j;
    while(titles1.length >= i) {
        if (searchBookInput === titles[i]) {
            return titles[i] + ' is available';
        }
        i++;
    } j++; i = 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the second while-loop ? It seems to say 'title1'. Is that what was intended ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to iterate over variable names, you may put your five arrays into an object and iterate over its keys like this:

```
var myObj = {
    titles1: ["The", "quick", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"],
    titles2: ["The", "quick", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"],
    titles3: ["The", "quick", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"],
    titles4: ["The", "quick", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"],
    titles5: ["The", "quick", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]
};

for (var key in myObj) {
    var array = myObj[key]; //array will be titles1, titles2, ...
    //do your stuff here...        
}
```

This works, because in JavaScript, you may access an object's value two ways:

```
object.someValue
```

and

```
object["someValue"]
```

Comment: Yes .. this is also possible. But, in this solution the keys seem to be limited to some n ? You could probably assign myObj to the titles first and then iterate as mentioned in the for-loop.

Comment: In this case (the for-key-in-loop) the limit is the number of keys in the object. If you want to limit it to "titles" 1 through 5, you may use a for-loop and do `var array = myObj["titles" + i]` on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use a multidimensional array for that instead of adding a number to the names (which is not possible btw):

```
var i = 0;
var j = 1;
var titles = new Array();

while (j <= 5){ // building your two-dimensional array
    var array = new Array();
    titles[j] = array;
    j++;
}

while(j <= 5) {
    while(titles[j].length <= i) {
        if (searchBookInput === titles[j][i]) {
            return titles[j][i] + ' is available';
        }
        i++;
    }
j++;
i = 0;
}
```

Multidimensional array explanation: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/twodimensional.htm

Edit: I might have made a syntax error, javascript has been a while for me.

Comment: ohh so it is not possible :( thanks for your answer. I need to create parallel arrays and that is why I have 5 arrays like that. I will just pack more data into one array then, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by parrallel?

Comment: @mad.mix also don't be to hasty to accept an answer as the correct one better ones might just come up like the one from Stacky

Comment: arrays that will share the same index number, for example 1 array with book names and another one with genres, first book will match genre in second array :)

Comment: @mad.mix a two dimensional array would be ideal for that because it is basicly the programatical equivalent of a table: http://www.programiz.com/sites/tutorial2program/files/two-dimensional-array.jpg I would suggest looking in to it because it's used a lot in programming ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could create a multidimensional object whereby each object houses a set of books with corresponding titles like so:

```
searchBookInput = "The Martian"

books = [{"title" : "The Martian"}, {"title" : "War And Peace"}, {"title" : "The Art of War"}]
comics = [{"title" : "Ms Marvel"}, {"title" : "Saga"}, {"title": "The Walking Dead"}]

books.filter(function(book) {return book.title == searchBookInput})
// Returns the object with the title matching searchBookInput
comics.filter(function(toon) {return toon.title == searchBookInput})
// Returns no object as no comic matches searchBookInput
```

This could be easier than needing the iterations for the multidimensional array.

Answer (score -2):

I think **eval** might be your friend here. eval solutions are not entirely ideal since it pollutes the global namespace (I think). So, another solution might be to:

```
var i = 0; var j = 1; var titles = '';
while(j <= 5) {
    titles = eval('titles' + j);
    while(titles.length >= i) {
        if (searchBookInput === titles[i]) {
            return titles[i] + ' is available';
        }
        i++;
    } j++; i = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a horrible solution and should definitely not be the accepted answer. Do not use constructed variable names, and definitely do not use `eval` to evaluate them. Instead, use an array to hold multiple things and use indexes to access their elements--that's what they are for.

Comment: you mean use an object and use it iterate ? btw, is there some reference about the solution being horrible ? :) I saw this: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/ Its a little dated.

Comment: I appreciate all the -ve votes. But there is not an explanation to learn why evals are much hated. Hated because its said OR hated for a reason  ?